# Camera Orientation

Tags: ios

i was working on a project related to  camera orientation. I wanted to know by changing UIDevice orientation programatically , does camera  orientation also changes?. or there is some other way do programatically change camera orientation , or only rotateing  the Device physically is the only option. thx

Comment: Did you try and sort out something ??

Comment: yes i did try using AvFoundation and UIimagePickerController but didnt get what i expected mb some 1 has done this so i posted here

Answer (score 0):

Using AVCaptureConnection you should be able to set the orientation.